# Styling two tables individually

Tags: html, css

I have two tables. How can I style them individually? I need to center the images with no border in table 1 and in table 2 I need to keep text left aligned with a border.

css:

```
table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid #999;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
th, td {
    padding: 10px;
}
```

html:

```
//table 2
<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <td>Jill</td>
    <td>Smith</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>John</td>
    <td>Doe</td>
  </tr>
</table>

//table 1
<table border="0" style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <td><img src="img1.png"></td>
    <td><img src="img2.png"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gqp6yg2z/1/)

add class on table1

```
  table, th, td {
        border: 1px solid #999;
        border-collapse: collapse;
    }
    th, td {
        padding: 10px;
    }

    .table1 td{
        text-align: center;
    }

.table1,.table1 td,.table1 tr{
    border: 0px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. But how can I have the border in tbl2 and no border in tbl1?

Answer (score 0):

Apply a class to each table and target the tables using the unique classes

HTML:

```
//table 2
<table class="first-table" style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <td>Jill</td>
    <td>Smith</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>John</td>
    <td>Doe</td>
  </tr>
</table>

//table 1
<table class="second-table" border="0" style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <td><img src="img1.png"></td>
    <td><img src="img2.png"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
.first-table {
  // first table styles here
}

.second-table {
  // second table styles here
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks. `.first-table, th, td {}  and `.second-table, th, td {}`  did not work. Should it be coma seperated?